# Apple Mach-O Linker Error duplicate architecture armv7 CCVideoPlayer cocos2d extension (cocos2d v2.0)

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5, ccvideoplayer

I'm trying to solve this linker error issue but I have no doubt, looked up for class duplicates or something else but nothing clear for now.

Did anyone faced this issue?

Seen [this post](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/242757?replies=2#post-399025) on cocos2d forum but commenting out the macros didn't helped me...

duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CCVideoPlayerImpl in:
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayer-9962022C0BCB5653.o
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayer-A41A32B34B96CC5E.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CCVideoPlayerImpl in:
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayer-9962022C0BCB5653.o
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayer-A41A32B34B96CC5E.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CCVideoPlayer in:
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayer-9962022C0BCB5653.o
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayer-A41A32B34B96CC5E.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CCVideoPlayer in:
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayer-9962022C0BCB5653.o
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayer-A41A32B34B96CC5E.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCVideoPlayerImpliOS._theMovie in:
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayerImpliOS-2E61FAAA0338656.o
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayerImpliOS-D9E5031DFFEFC61.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCVideoPlayerImpliOS._videoOverlayView in:
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayerImpliOS-2E61FAAA0338656.o
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayerImpliOS-D9E5031DFFEFC61.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCVideoPlayerImpliOS._delegate in:
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayerImpliOS-2E61FAAA0338656.o
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayerImpliOS-D9E5031DFFEFC61.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCVideoPlayerImpliOS._playing in:
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayerImpliOS-2E61FAAA0338656.o
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayerImpliOS-D9E5031DFFEFC61.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCVideoPlayerImpliOS.noSkip in:
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayerImpliOS-2E61FAAA0338656.o
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayerImpliOS-D9E5031DFFEFC61.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CCVideoPlayerImpliOS in:
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayerImpliOS-2E61FAAA0338656.o
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayerImpliOS-D9E5031DFFEFC61.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CCVideoPlayerImpliOS in:
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayerImpliOS-2E61FAAA0338656.o
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CCVideoPlayerImpliOS-D9E5031DFFEFC61.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_VideoOverlayView._touch in:
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/videoOverlayView-3F7278265D6C165F.o
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/videoOverlayView-24E20B177AADBD4D.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_VideoOverlayView in:
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/videoOverlayView-3F7278265D6C165F.o
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/videoOverlayView-24E20B177AADBD4D.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_VideoOverlayView in:
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/videoOverlayView-3F7278265D6C165F.o
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-cejlpqfnlpectralthclvyvltqkk/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/videoOverlayView-24E20B177AADBD4D.o
ld: 22 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are imported `CCVideoPlayer` **two times** in your `Xcode` project. Check your project resources, if it is there remove one.